# Select all dates after a cutoff day in current month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where I need to return all records loaded after a specific day of the current month, in a sense the cut off date of that month.

In my situation I need to return all values after the 9th of the current month.

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CUTOFFDAY INT
DECLARE @CUTOFFDATE DATETIME

SET @CUTOFFDAY = 9
SET @CUTOFFDATE = CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(getdate())AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@CUTOFFDAY AS varchar) AS DATETIME)

SELECT Date
FROM DateTable
WHERE ContractDate > @CUTOFF
```

DATE

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @cutoffday int = 9

select * from <yourtable>
where <yourdatefield> >= 
       dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp), @cutoffday - 1)
```